# Ruby String #{} doesn't work

Tags: ruby, string, string-interpolation

I have this is my code：

```
class Template
  def initialize(temp_str)
    @str = temp_str
  end

  def render options={}
    @str.gsub!(/{{/,'#{options[:').gsub!(/}}/,']}')
    puts @str
  end
end

template = Template.new("{{name}} likes {{animal_type}}")
template.render(name: "John", animal_type: "dogs")
```

I was hoping the result would be `John likes dogs`, but it was

```
#{options[:name]} likes #{options[:animal_type]}
```

Why doesn't the `#{}` get interpolated?

Comment: I love it when a person that misinterprets a concept ends up thinking that much out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. While it has received a couple of downvotes from people who might think this question is unnecessary, it is actually a pretty good question for Stack Overflow with well trimmed code and a clear example. I would be delighted if every question we get here was that clear. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#{}` is not some magic that gets converted to interpolation whenever it occurs. It's a **literal** syntax for interpolating. Here you are not writing it literally, you get it by doing a replacement. Instead, you could do something like:

```
template = "{{name}} likes {{animal_type}}"
options  = {name: 'John', animal_type: 'dogs'}
template.gsub(/{{(.*?)}}/) { options[$1.to_sym] } # => "John likes dogs"
```

This captures the name inside the moustaches and indexes the hash with it.

---

Even better would be to utilize the existing [format functionality](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-25). Instead of moustaches, use `%{}`:

```
template = "%{name} likes %{animal_type}"
options  = {name: 'John', animal_type: 'dogs'}
template % options # => "John likes dogs"
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation, now i understand. Thank you very much.